# Unable to fetch the value of Println in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

```scala
scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

scala> object  rddTest{
 | def main(args: Array[String]) = {
 | val spark =  SparkSession.builder.appName("mapExample").master("local").getOrCreate()
 | val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1,"jan",2016),(3,"nov",2014),(16,"feb",2014)))
 | val rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((5,"dec",2014),(17,"sep",2015)))
 | val rdd3 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((6,"dec",2011),(16,"may",2015)))
 | val rddUnion = rdd1.union(rdd2).union(rdd3)
 | rddUnion.foreach(Println)
 | }
 | }
```

I am getting this error ,i dont know why this is coming

> < console>:81: error: not found: value Println
>          rddUnion.foreach(Println)

Comment: p is lowercase, `println`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extrat upper case try this :

```
rddUnion.foreach(println)
```